# width and height adjustments on only youtube iframes

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

how to make adjustments on width and height for all youtube embeds only, because there are some iframes that is used and mostly are youtubes

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xbGv2T456dfg3">
```

this codes is embedded in my wordpress post, I want to adjust the width and height for only youtube iframes and not all iframes, I can adjust manually but when it comes to many videos then it will be long to do.

for example
* all youtube iframes will be 560x316
* and all other iframes will be its default dimension.

can it be done in php? sorry Im new

Comment: are you fetching these via a DB?

Comment: no, just want to have all my video post in the same proportion without adjust all of them one by one

Comment: most likely you can use javascript and do a regular expression on the source and change the h/w. I'm not too sure if you can do this because it's a iframe and most browsers don't allow you to access the iframe for security measures.

Comment: is that so, Im am very new at this, but thanks for the info

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new [filter on the_content](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) in your theme's functions PHP that calls a function that searches for and replaces Youtube iframes like this:

```
function my_youtube_resizer($content) {
   $dom=new DOMDocument();
   $dom->loadHTML($content);
   $iframess = $dom->getElementsByTagName("iframe");       
   foreach ($iframes as $iframe) {
     $src = $iframe->getAttribute('src');
     if (strpos('youtube.com', $src)) {  //You may have to also deal with the short URL youtu.be
        $iframe->setAttribute('width', '560');
        $iframe->setAttribute('height', '316');
     }
   }
   $content = $dom->saveHTML();
   return $content;
 }
```

If you're using another plugin to create those iframe links (e.g. Jetpack), make sure your filter has a lower priority.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [css attribute selectors](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3attributeselectors) to choose iframes with `youtube.com` in the src attribute:

```css
iframe[src*="youtube.com"], 
iframe[src*="youtu.be"] {
    width: 560px !important;
    height: 316px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys for the help

I just gave jquery a shot and it worked

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('iframe[src*="youtube.com"]').css({"width":"560px","height":"316px"});
    });
```